# Akka: Send Message to All Actors of System Using Java

Tags: java, akka

I am new to Akka.

Just want to know whether I can send a message to all the actors created by the system without explicitly using their ActorRef?

Many thanks.

Comment: I was thinking you could achieve this with a very broad actor selection, but I don't think you can actually do this unless your system is flat (no actors as children of other actors).  If you really need to do this, then using the Event Bus might be your best bet.  Have all of your custom actors subscribe into a particular custom event and then publish that event from somewhere else and they all will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`BroadcastRouter`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#BroadcastRouter) albeit all destinations needs to be a routee of the router.

> A broadcast router forwards the message it receives to all its routees